# Java generics meaning of <?>

Tags: java, generics

Sometimes I see java code which looks like

```
Class<?>
```

and I don't understand the proper meaning of it.

If I see something like:

```
ComboBox<Order> box = new ComboBox<>();
```

then its clear that box can only contain Objects from the class Order, but what about `<?>`?  Is it equal to  or something completely different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a **wildcard**, it just means you don't need to specify the generic type. It is sometimes useful, but should not be used in general. One case where you can use it safely is when you use a type bound :

```
public void withWildCard(List<? extends Collection<Integer>> collections) { 
    ...
}

public void withoutWildCard(List<Collection<Integer>> collections) { 
    ...
}

List<Collection<Integer>> listOfCollections;
withWildcard(listOfCollections); // valid call
withoutWildcard(listOfCollections); // valid call

List<List<Integer>> listOfLists;
withWildcard(listOfLists); // valid call becase List is a subclass of Collection
withoutWildcard(listOfLists); // invalid call, does not compile because List does not match Collection
```

By the way, the snippet in your question is wrong. It should be

```
ComboBox<Order> box = new ComboBox<>();
```

If you don't specify the generic type in the declaration side, the compiler won't be able to infer the type of the diamond operator (`<>`).

Comment: please check your answer. I don't see any difference between the two methods

Comment: Haha, copy pasting is bad... Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: So is '<?>' equal to '<Object>'?

Comment: This is how it is going to be compiled, but it is not really equivalent. For example you cannot do `List<Object> x = ...; List<?> y = x`. Actually I tried some things with `List<?>` and I could not add anything to it whereas it compiles fine for `List<Object>`. This makes me think that ? should only be used when there is a bound on the type (for example `? super A`, otherwise you have absolutely no clue on the type